# modify data in columns in SQL Server

Tags: c#, ms-access, web

I am trying to make a website written in C# in Visual Studio 2010. I got a database in .accdb extention.

So I go a table in the database called `usertb`, and in the table `username` is the key, and the data `password` and `DOB` in columns.

Now I need to make a function to edit a user profile, which lets the user to enter a new password and Date of Birth. After that, it will save to the database.

I don't know why the code seems to be not working. I tried to use

```
UPDATE ... SET ...WHERE ..
```

function but I don't know why it doesn't allow me to do that (is that because my code is written in C# but not PHP?)

Here is the code for edit user profile:   (`srpassword` is the name of the password column, `password` is the new one user typed in)

```
public static bool EditUserInfo(string username, string password)
{
    string query = "SELECT REPLACE([srpassword], [srpassword], 'password')
                    FROM usertb WHERE srusername = '" + username + "'";
    accessDB dbaccess = new accessDB();
    return dbaccess.saveData(query);
}
```

Hope somebody can help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try `"UPDATE usertb SET [srpassword] = '" + password + "' WHERE [srusername] = '" + username + "'`?

I'm not going in details why Access is a bad choice, if you're using it only for prototyping it should be OK though.

Comment: Vladislav, I think that @Vash option is better because use Parameters instead of concat values to the query...

Comment: Of course it's better, I was just trying not to complicate things too much (for now). First get it working, then make it robust :)

Comment: You're welcome, now take a look at the other answer or search in google: "c# parametrized query" :) Believe me, not only will it make your code more readable, but also much more secure (SQL injection becomes impossible) and fast (i.e. if you reuse the same query in a loop).

Answer (score 3):

The syntax select replace is from MySQL, in SQL Server the update statements goes like [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa260662%28v=sql.80%29.aspx)

Also I'm no sure about that `accessDB dbaccess = new accessDB();`, has the connection etc.

Also instead of combining statement you should use parameters, then your statement should look like this.

```
UPDATE usertb SET srpassowr = @password WHERE srusername = @userName;
```

As you have some class responsible for connection to db this [example](http://weblogs.asp.net/cibrax/archive/2006/09/28/Parameterized-Queries-_2800_Oracle_2C00_-SQLServer_2C00_-OleDb_2900_.aspx) show how usually sql statemetns should be executed.